# Node.js on Windows10: installing sqlite3 module errors

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have installed node.js directly on my Windows10 computer. For development work this is more quick than the docker version.

Installing the module sqlite3 module gives a lot of errors. AFter installing python2.7 I get the error (below).

I don't want to install all kinds of compilers on my computer. Is there a simple way to get the sqlite3 node.js module on my computer?

I translated the error in english:

MSBUILD : error MSB3428: cannot load the Visual C++-part VCBuild.exe. YOu can solve this by 1) installing the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the part to your system path if it is already installed.  [C:\User
s\Johan\node_only\node-sqlite\node_modules\sqlite3\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Comment: If Node 5.8 is suitable for you then you can use precompiled module (see more https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3)

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do/get this?

Comment: Install `pre-gyp` by `npm i node-pre-gyp -g` and next run `npm i sqlite3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need to follow those instructions.

Edit:

Your two options are:

1. install an old SDK

or

2. install an old Visual Studio

Option 1 is more effective because:

1. You will never use that old version of visual studio
2. Installing the old visual studio will probably prompt you do download the old SDK
3. Visual studio takes up a lot of memory in comparison to the SDK
4. SDK installation takes less time and is more straight-forward

Comment: Just for adding a very small access method from node.js to a database file, it looks a lot to install. Which of the 3 optiones do you advice AND which is minimal for my Windows10 installation?

Comment: Will it not conflict with the rest of my computer?

Comment: nope, it's only used when it's specifically needed.

Comment: Also please +1 and mark as solution if you found my answer helpful. :)

Comment: Is [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displayLang=en&id=8279) an old sdk, it is not available.